# Black and white Italian movie where an audience member gets shot

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a black and white Italian movie that I saw a while back during an Italian film fest in Munich.

Here are the few plot details I remember:

- The story has a surreal/fantastic plot, that involves a murder happening in a movie theatre full of spectators watching a Western movie (I think).
- During the movie screening one of the spectators gets shot. The movie theatre gets put on lock-down, and spectators are interviewed individually by a team (or a single) detective(s). As the detective(s) interview key suspects, their diverse backgrounds and characters are developed.
- In an attempt to shed light onto how the crime happened, the detective(s) suggest re-enacting the movie screening. Spectators take their seats, the Western movie restarts, and at the exact time when the first murder happened, *another* shot is heard resulting in yet another death.

I'm not exactly sure how the plot progressed from there, but the surreal/fantastical ending involved the discovery that one of the Western movie characters had fired the shot, into the audience, thereby killing the two spectators.

Some technical details: It was an old black and white movie in Italian with English subtitles.

Comment: Hmm. I seem to recall a similar question somewhere else. Not sure it got an answer.

Comment: This seems a little familiar -- don't recall a title, but it sounds like something Frederico Fellini might have perpetrated.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I'm not sure about Fellini. If so perhaps one of his earlier films. I think the plot/movie was set sometime in the 60s. It was an impressive movie, with a strong eerie and surreal atmosphere.

Comment: @Paulie_D If you do recall a similar/earlier question, please share the link. I'm quite vague on some parts of the plot, so any further clues would help.

Comment: That sort of surreal plus Italian just added up to Fellini, to me.  I'm quite likely to be wrong, as I'm neither a film expert nor a real Fellini fan.

Comment: Aw, I was thinking this was about a B-movie theater gimmick where there was a plant in *the actual audience* who got "shot".

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is the 1978 *[Closed Circuit](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077337/?ref_=tt_urv)* directed by Giuliano Montaldo, originally released as *Circuito chiuso*. The synopsis on IMDb describes the premise:

> A man is shot dead in his seat during a matinee screening of a Giuliano Gemma Spaghetti Western, prompting the police to close off the cinema in an attempt to gather evidence.

^_^ One of those times where I got frustrated and just typed in a full question into Google and got an answer, *italian film audience member shot by character in a western*.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's allowed here to link to a full movie on YouTube (even a foreign one)...

Comment: Trailers are preferred, but mainly because they stick around longer.

Comment: I did come across this relevant discussion on meta: [Youtube usage policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/youtube-usage-policy)

Comment: I haven't been able to find a trailer. Link removed.